# Extracting Time-Series NDVI values to points using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working on a study that compares standard deviation of sentinel NDVI images. I want to extract NDVI values using a random points from a set of NDVI images using Google Earth Engine.

Here's my code:

```
var Date_Start = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
var Date_End = ee.Date('2020-06-30');
//var Date_window = ee.Number(30);

// Create list of dates for time series
var n_months = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'week').round();
print(n_months, "no. of weeks")
var dates = ee.List.sequence(2,n_months,2);
print(dates, "week list")
var make_datelist = function(n) {
  return Date_Start.advance(n,'week');
};
dates = dates.map(make_datelist);
print(dates,"dates")

var fnc = function(d1) {
  var date = ee.Date(d1).format("YYYY-MM-dd")
  var start = ee.Date(d1);
  var end = ee.Date(d1).advance(5,'day');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start,end);
  var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filterDate(date_range)

    .filterBounds(GG);
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

  return S2.mosaic().normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).clip(GG)
};

var list_of_images = dates.map(fnc);
print('list_of_images', list_of_images);
var ndviCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list_of_images);
 
var NDVImean = ndviCol.mean();
var NDVIsd = ndviCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());
var NDVIcv = NDVIsd.divide(NDVImean); 


Map.addLayer(NDVIsd, null, 'NDVIsd');

print(ndviCol)
var ndviMultiTemp = ndviCol.toBands();
print(ndviMultiTemp);
Map.centerObject(GG, 7)


Map.addLayer(ndviCol.first(), {min:-1, max:1}, 'NDVI');
// EXPORT Tools

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: NDVIsd.clip(GG),
  description: 'B2B3NDVIsd', 
  crs: 'EPSG:32637',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  folder: 'LULC_2020_NDVIsd', 
  region: GG.geometry(),
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels:3784216672431,
  skipEmptyTiles: true
  });
```

Comment: Where are your issues?

Comment: **Thanks @xunilk for your instant reply!** I have 13 different NDVI images in 26 weeks, as well as 1000 sample vector points, as I mentioned in the previous section. My problem is that I want to use the sample points to derive NDVI values from the 13 NDVI images. My goal is to have a point with 13 NDVI values in 13 columns.